# How to get session or redis key's expiration time in controller when using Spring's @EnableRedisHttpSession?

Tags: spring-boot, redis, httpsession, spring-data-redis, spring-session

I am using Spring Boot and Spring session. Here is my simple config.

```
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class Config {}
```

Spring Boot by default creates a `RedisConnectionFactory` and I put corresponding `host`, `port` information etc in `application.yml` file(removed for brevity)

I also added security related information(removed it from here for brevity).

Now this is my controller.

```
@RestController
public HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String home(HttpSession session){
        // I need redis's key's expiration time. or session id's expiration time. 
        // how can I get this? Should I use HttpSession?
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

How do I get session expiration time in my controller? or rather how can I get redis's key's expiration time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [HttpSession](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)

You can add it as a parameter in your controller method as shown below(also shown in question).

```
@GetMapping("/hello")
public String home(HttpSession session){
    // I need redis's key's expiration time. or session id's expiration time. 
    // how can I get this? Should I use HttpSession?
    int ttl = session.getMaxInactiveInterval(); // this should give redis TTL
    return "hello";
}
```

And you can use HttpSession's [getMaxInactiveInterval](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getMaxInactiveInterval--) method to get redis's TTL value as shown in the code above.

Comment: Hey, I saw your [question about Handlebars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59381572/how-to-get-dynamic-object-key-in-if-condition-in-handlebars#59381572) earlier. Did you find a solution yet? If not, I gave it a try here: https://jsfiddle.net/zaje7duf/3/